# Use of Factory class that returns ImplInterface inside interface

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I was exploring the [CallbackManager](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/main/java/com/facebook/CallbackManager.java) class in Facebook SDK and noticed something interesting,

They declare an `interface` and there they use a static class `Factory` that returns the implementation of this Interface. I never seen something like that, can anyone explain why that use needed??

```
public interface CallbackManager { 

    public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);



    public static class Factory { 
        /** 
         * Creates an instance of {@link com.facebook.CallbackManager}. 
         * @return an instance of {@link com.facebook.CallbackManager}. 
         */ 
        public static CallbackManager create() { 
            return new CallbackManagerImpl(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you never seen a Factory patten before and you're asking why use that?  Or are you asking about this specific implementation of it?  Because a factory pattern is fairly common.

Comment: Exposing an interface, hiding the implementation. Nothing new here. Check out the `Executors` class, which exposes `ExecutorService` for methods like [`newFixedThreadPool`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.newFixedThreadPool%28int%29), but returns the actual implementation.

Comment: @GabeSechan, No I don't ask about Factory, as you can read from the title...The question is about this implementation

Comment: It allows the developer to change which implementation is being used. [Dependency inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). Check out [Why would a programmer want to separate implementation from interface?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/142192/why-would-a-programmer-want-to-separate-implementation-from-interface)

Comment: In enterprise(s) they use service locators to look for the implementations of this interface, it varies by the requirements of the project. But, yeah this is a standard practice across.